# Convert excel to datatable in c#?

Tags: c#

How to convert excel to datatable in c# using interop.
I am getting issues while converting excel.
I am new to dot net. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below function which will convert excel to datatable. You just need to pass excel path to this function and this function will return the datatable:

```
public DataTable READExcel(string path)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objXL = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook objWB = null;
        objXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        objWB = objXL.Workbooks.Open(path);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet objSHT = objWB.Worksheets[1];

        int rows = objSHT.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
        int cols = objSHT.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        int noofrow = 1;

        for (int c = 1; c <= cols; c++)
        {
            string colname = objSHT.Cells[1, c].Text;
            dt.Columns.Add(colname);
            noofrow = 2;
        }

        for (int r = noofrow; r <= rows; r++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            for (int c = 1; c <= cols; c++)
            {
                dr[c - 1] = objSHT.Cells[r, c].Text;
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        objWB.Close();
        objXL.Quit();
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

In .Net core you can use Syncfusion.XlsIO 
Install-Package Syncfusion.XlsIO.Net.Core -Version 17.2.0.49

```
    private DataTable ConvertExcelToDataTable(string path)
    {
            using (Stream inputStream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())
                {
                    IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;
                    IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(inputStream);
                    IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

                    DataTable dataTable = worksheet.ExportDataTable(worksheet.UsedRange, ExcelExportDataTableOptions.ColumnNames);
                    return dataTable;
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: You made my day!